# equality of two natural transformations and two morphisms

Tags: category-theory

When are two natural transformations between two functors considered the same?  When are two morphisms in a category considered the same? Do we have such a notion like we have in Set theory? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As @Zhen Lin and others noted, the notion of equality is sometimes debated.

I personally like the following approach since it is quite general.

In the constructive school of thought, a category is a type of objects, arrows, composition,
and identities satisfying certain laws, but moreover it is **also equipped with an equivalence
relation on arrows** of the same type: given $f, g : A ⟶ B$ morphisms in the category, we can
form the expression $f ≈ g$. Notice that it need not be strict equality but any equivalence
relation, and it is on the morphisms not the objects.

Then the problem of *morphism equality* is solved by the implementer, the one who defined the
equality, and so the user (of the category) need not worry about it (or about having to make a
choice of when two things are 'equal'). For example, the morphism-equivalence in one category
might be an isomorphism in simpler category!

⟦
The reason that there is no corresponding notion of equality of objects, in the constructivist approach, is that categories are all about morphisms not objects and usually one uses object-isomorphism anyways.
⟧

Time for an example. Suppose we have two categories  and , with morphism-equalities ≈₀ and ≈₁, then
the functor category $Func \;  \; = [, ] =  ^ $ may be defined to have morphism (ie natural
transformation) equality to be pointwise:
$γ ≈ η \;⇔\; (∀ x • γ_x \;≈_1\; η_x)$ ---notice that we're using the equality of -morphisms.

Another example: The category of categories  has equality of functors ≈ being
pointwise equalities $$F ≈ G :  ⟶  \;⇔\; (∀ x : Obj \, • F x = G x)$$ $$∀ f, g : Arrow •\; f \; ≈_0 \; g \;\;⇒\;\; F f \;≈_1\; F g$$
Where ,  have morphism equalities ≈₀ and ≈₁, respectively.
Alternatively, one may define $F ≈ G ⇔ (∀ x • F x ≅ G x \text{ in  and naturally so in $x$})$, i.e.,
functor-isomorphism and then the functor category, is by this particular construction, skeletal(!): all isomorphisms
are equality. Why you want this is another matter.

Finally note that a common construction is to define an equivalence relation on morphisms
then quotient by it to obtain equivalence classes and then consider this category, each time
having to prove well-definedness due to the usage of representatives. This now becomes
by proving operations are congruences.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful.

Comment: please could you explain the dot notation?

Comment: The LaTeX `\bullet` is a syntactic separator between the quantifier variables and the quantification body. You can read more about it by looking up `Z notation`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this question is equivalent to the question "When are two elements of a set considered same?" The answer is "When they are equal".

Indeed, let $C$ be a category, $f,g\in Arr(C)$ be its morphisms. Then $f=g$ as morphisms iff $f=g$ as elements of the set $Arr(C)$.

Let $C$ and $D$ be categories, $T,S\colon C\to D$ be functors, $\alpha,\beta\colon T\to S$ be natural transformations. Then $\alpha=\beta$ as natural transformations iff $\alpha(c)=\beta(c)$ for every $c\in Ob(C)$. Equivalently, $\alpha=\beta$ as natural transformations iff $\alpha=\beta$ as elements of $Nat(T,S)$ - the set of natural transformations between $T$ and $S$. This set consists of mappings $Ob(C)\to Arr(D)$ with additional properties (subsets of $Ob(C)\times Arr(D)$ with additional properties), so its elements are equal when they are equal as mappings (as subsets of $Ob(C)\times Arr(D)$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was under the impression that category theory allows two copies of the same thing (morphisms, functors) to be distinct. But, that would be very difficult to work with, I guess! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, equality of objects in a category or functors between categories is a contested issue...

Comment: @sumit You are welcome. Note, that sometimes the difference between the different notions in category theory is a bit sophisticated (and sometimes even contested, as Zhen Lin mentioned). For instance, two categories may be equal, isomorphic or equivalent, and all these relations are different.

Comment: @Zhen Lin- I see. Thanks.