# What defines arrows equality

Tags: category-theory

I have decided to learn basics of category theory, but have stumbled upon the very first exercise: given a category C, prove that identity arrow is *unique* among arrows with domain of X and codomain of X, where X is from the objects of the given category C. But I fail to see or find any definition of arrows equality or inequality. In other words, given 2 arrows: $f:X\to Y $ and $g:X\to Y$, how can I say if they are same or not?

Comment: Arthur has given a good answer, it seems to me.  But maybe you can help me understand your question better by giving an example on a similar question:  Given two natural numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ how can you say if they are the same or not?

Comment: @ColinMcLarty after few revisions he did indeed, I changed my downvote to upvote and most probably will accept it soon. Regarding your question: I have no clue.

Comment: One way to think of a category is as a set (its set of morphisms) with an additional structure, call it a *category structure* if you will, over the set of its objects. Your question and @colin-mclarty's reduce to asking how to show that two elements in a set, with some additional structure, are equal. As in Arthur's answer, you use the properties of the given structure on the set (of morphisms in a category for you question and $\mathbb{N}$ for @colin-mclarty's).

Comment: Some insist on a notion of ``morphism equality'' as part of the definition of  a category; http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1655918/80406 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say you have two identity arrows $\operatorname{Id}_1, \operatorname{Id}_2:X\to X$. By the defining property of identity arrow, we have
$$
\operatorname{Id}_1 = \operatorname{Id}_1\circ \operatorname{Id}_2 = \operatorname{Id}_2
$$
and thus the two are equal.

Basically, the axioms and definitions of your theory will tell you when two things are equal. In this case, an identity arrow $\operatorname{Id}:X\to X$ is defined by the following: for any $f:X\to Y$ and any $g:Z\to X$, we have $f = f\circ{\operatorname{Id}}$ and $g = {\operatorname{Id}}\circ g$. One can deduce general results (usually called theorems) which will assist you in less simple cases so you don't have to appeal directly to the axioms all the time, but in the end, all equalities are proven from whatever equalities your axioms and definitions give you.

Exactly how you should prove that $f$ and $g$ in your question are equal will depend greatly on how they are defined, and what you know about the category in which you are working. Some categories only have one arrow for each (ordered) pair of objects, and in that case, they will automatically be equal. Other categories are more complicated. In most common categories, like the categories of groups (abelian or general), topological spaces, and so on, equality of arrows is not commonly shown on a category theoretical level, although some specific cases can benefit greatly from a category theoretical formulation.

Comment: I have not asked how to proof this statement. I have asked which 2 arrows are considered equal, and which are not.

Comment: @Arkadiy I have added a paragraph about that.

Comment: I think this answer is still not specific enough =(

Answer (score 0):

This question has bugged me for a long time.  Honestly, the fact that there is not a straightforward, satisfactory answer here tends to make me think that there are only like 100 people in the entire world who do category theory.  Anyways, I finally found what I guess is a satisfactory answer to the question, but it's not quite as easy as I wish it were...

There is a nice text called [FUNCTORIAL SEMANTICS OF ALGEBRAIC THEORIES AND SOME ALGEBRAIC PROBLEMS IN THE CONTEXT OF FUNCTORIAL SEMANTICS OF ALGEBRAIC THEORIES](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/5/tr5.pdf) by Lawvere.  I haven't digested all the material or even finished it - but I could say that about every single thing ever written about category theory.  I guess this dude is old school enough to throw in a few logical symbols when going through the basic definitions, axioms, etc.

The following formula appears on page 27:

$$ \forall \mathbb{A}, \forall \mathbb{B}, \forall f, \forall g,
\Big[\,
\mathbb{A} \xrightarrow{\;\; f\;\;} \mathbb{B}
\,\land\,
\mathbb{A} \xrightarrow{\;\; g\;\;} \mathbb{B}
\,\land\,
\forall u \,[
2 \xrightarrow{\;\; u\;\;} \mathbb{A} \Rightarrow uf = ug
] \Rightarrow
f = g
\,\Big]
$$

Here, $2$ is the category $\cdot\to \cdot$

Roughly speaking, two arrows are equal if no other arrow could distinguish them.  I'm not sure if this is truly an *axiom* of category theory, or if it follows from some more fundamental definitions, but I have no problem taking it as an axiom given that this seemingly important issue seems to have been disregarded in general.  Like most things in category theory, I'm not sure if this will help you calculate anything, but it's at least *something.*

**EDIT** Well, for what it's worth, just take $u = \mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{A}}$.

Comment: I appreciate a comment with the downvote.